# How to dispose a service implementing IAsyncDisposable using Dependency Injection in .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, idisposable, iasyncdisposable

I am having a service that uses the `IAsyncDisposable` interface, because it holds an object that has the interface itself.

```cs
public class AddressImporter : IAddressImporter
{
    private readonly IConsumer<Model> _consumer; // implementing IAsyncDisposable
}
```

I register the service like this:
`services.AddTransient<IAddressImporter, AddressImporter>();`
And inject it into my main service like this:

```cs
public MainService(IAddressImporter addressImporter) {
    _addressImporter = addressImporter;
}
```

Will this leak the resource? If so how can I improve this, so `DisposeAsync` is called on any exception in my main service?

I was thinking of adding `IAsyncDisposable` to `IAddressImporter` and calling `IAddressImporter.DisposeAsync` on any exception or the end of my `MainService`.

EDIT:
When trying to use the service

```cs
public class AddressImporter : IAddressImporter
{
    private readonly IConsumer<Model> _consumer; // implementing IAsyncDisposable
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _logger.Information("Disposing {ResourceName}", nameof(PulsarAddressImporter));
        await _consumer.DisposeAsync();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

}
```

I get the exception:

> BackgroundService failed System.InvalidOperationException: 'AddressService.Web.Jobs.Test' type only implements IAsyncDisposable. Use DisposeAsync to dispose the container. System.InvalidOperationException: 'AddressService.Web.Jobs.Test' type only implements IAsyncDisposable. Use DisposeAsync to dispose the container. [15:23:56 INF] Application is shutting down...

Comment: Services created by the DI container are disposed by the DI container automatically. How is `_consumer` created? If it's created by DI, it will be disposed automatically. If it's created by `AddressImporter`, that class's `Dispose` or `DisposeAsync` should also dispose `_consumer`

Comment: This works for me with Dispose, but not with IAsyncDisposable
When using IAsyncDisposable I get an Exception telling me to call DisposeAsync.
It's created by DI.

Comment: Post the actual *full* exception in the question itself. What's `AddressImporter`'s actual code? Does it implement `IAsyncDisposable` or `IDisposable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will this leak the resource?

It depends on lifecycle of the parent object and scope - services created by build-in DI container are disposed automatically when the scope is disposed:

```cs
class MyTransient : IAsyncDisposable
{
    public bool Disposed { get; set; }
    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        Disposed = true;
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }
}

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<MyTransient>();

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
MyTransient myTransient;
await using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateAsyncScope())
{
    myTransient = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyTransient>();
}

Console.WriteLine(myTransient.Disposed); // prints True
```

So unless the service is created from the root one it will disposed with everything else when the owner scope ends, so making `AddressImporter` implementing `IDisposable/IAsyncDisposable` should do the trick (if the exception leads to end of the owner scope).

Comment: This works for me with Dispose, but not with IAsyncDisposable
When using IAsyncDisposable I get an Exception telling me to call DisposeAsync

Comment: @TeaJ what project type do you have? ASP.NET Core? Console? WPF/WinForms/MAUI? The provided code works, the mentioned exception as far as I remember will happen if `using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())` is used.

Comment: BackgroundService failed
System.InvalidOperationException: 'AddressService.Web.Jobs.Test' type only implements IAsyncDisposable. Use DisposeAsync to dispose the container.
System.InvalidOperationException: 'AddressService.Web.Jobs.Test' type only implements IAsyncDisposable. Use DisposeAsync to dispose the container.
[15:23:56 INF] Application is shutting down...

Comment: My example was: 
public interface ITest
{

}
public class Test: ITest, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public Test(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _logger.Information("disposed");
    }
}
services.AddTransient<ITest, Test>();

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Core Web Application

Comment: @TeaJ `BackgroundService` usually means a singleton lifetime. Are you creating a scope inside it?

Comment: Ah ok, I am using a bigger library that seems to create singletons.

Comment: @TeaJ what is triggering the disposal? Can you share some [mre]? Either way, if the library is out of your control - you will need to implement `IDisposable` or dispose manually (maybe moving everything into factory).

Comment: Well I would hope that the DI container, would trigger the disposal.
Sharing a minimal reproducible example is hard, because of the library being closed source. Implementing IDisposable and calling _consumer.DisposeAsync().AsTask().Wait(); seems to work. The factory is another possibility I was thinking of.
But it is good to know that it normally should be working.